# Rspec and Watir; use array param as for an element index

Tags: arrays, ruby, rspec, watir-webdriver

Running GUI tests using Rspec.  Is it possible for me to pass an array of values and have them used as the index position for an element?

Something like:

```
def pin_specific_idxs(*idx)
    pins = foo.divs(:class => 'some-element', :index => idx).div(:class, 'another-element').button(:class, 'thingy-i-want-to-click')
    pins.each do |pin|
        pin.click
    end
end
```

So in testing, I would call `pin_specific_idxs(0,2,3)`

Is that doable or do I have to explicitly call individual index values every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 things:

- Iterate over the passed in indices rather than passing the whole Array as a parameter to `:index`
- Locate the specific `div` rather than `divs` using the `:index` (ie element collections do not support the `:index` locator)

This would look like:

```
def pin_specific_idxs(*idxs)
  idxs.each do |idx|
    foo.div(:class => 'some-element', :index => idx)
       .div(:class, 'another-element')
       .button(:class, 'thingy-i-want-to-click')
       .click
  end
end
```